# How to edit content more easily?

Tags: confluence

i add content to my confluence page like a html
inside {html} tags. This page will be changed in future every week. It very difficult to understand html so quick for people who never don't work with html.
Is there any way in confluence to add a simple user interface form which helps to edit information inside html? 
I know that confluence have embedded jQuery can anybody give advice how to do it better?

Thanks

Comment: Could you add some information what problem you have to solve by editing the same page every week? What is the information that has to be changed or edited? Is it like a formular with the same information all the time, or more free form but html help to layout the page nicer?

Comment: Only one person who responsible for adding information every week to this page. Content on this page implemented in html, and one problem that this person don't know html and how to edit it. Yesterday i write a simple programm with simple UI that use jsoup. This programm parse data, and show fields which need to change. It works, i don't know is good way or not but anyway it resolve this problem. It save some time i think it's not bad. Thnx all.

Answer (score 1):

Use the scaffolding plugin to Show only some special text fields for editing. Then you can hide the HTML code. But scaffolding is not ready for Confluence 4

http://wiki.customware.net/repository/display/AtlassianPlugins/Scaffolding+Plugin

Answer (score 1):

You could download the page with Atlassian CLI, and parse out the section of html you want to modify, put that in your wysiwyg, and then inject it back into the downloaded html and post it back.

Of course it is as fun as it sounds.

Answer (score 0):

An example of the content would help to answer this question.
One option is to put your content in a word .doc file, save it, upload it to the page. Use the [office connector](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.confluence.extra.officeconnector) macro to display the content of the .doc on the page. The office connector plugin is free.

Note that Confluence V5 editor now has a basic set of editing features found in Microsoft Word.